# GET and parameterless GET causing AmbiguousActionException?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to have two Web API methods in my controller. One for when GET is called with a `MyViewModel` object in the header, and one without.

MyController.cs:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<UserModel> Get()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<UserModel> Get(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But browsing to the route address in Chrome without passing any `MyViewModel` gives me this error:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> MyController.Get (MyProject)
>
> MyController.Get (MyProject)

If I comment out the parameterless method and put a break point in the parameterized function and browse to the api URL, it looks like rather than the `viewModel` being `null` like I expected, it appears to be a new `MyViewModel` object made with a parameterless constructor. Seems like it may be relevant to my problem.

I'm running on **Microsoft.AspNetCore v1.1.2** and **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc v1.1.3**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add attribute routing to one of them. 
For example:

```
    [HttpGet("/myaction")]   
    public IEnumerable<UserModel> Get(MyViewModel viewModel)
   {
    // ...
   }
```

Or add it to all of them. MVC can't distinguish two methods because `viewModel` can be null, and doesn't know if it should match first get `action` or another.

Answer (score 1):

> One for when GET is called with a MyViewModel object in the header, and one without.

[Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) in ASP.NET Core by default uses query parameters as the source for model population, not headers. If you need to fill `MyViewModel` from the header, use `[FromHeader]` attribute:

```
public IEnumerable<UserModel> Get([FromHeader] MyViewModel viewModel)
```

---

ASP.NET Core [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) implementation is not using headers for routing resolving. As you are using attribute routing, as @Vlado said, you need to use different Route Name for disambiguating actions.